# Как читать значения переменных android

Tags: android, бот

Я хочу написать бота к одной игре. Я все продумал, но столкнулся с одной проблемой - как узнать координаты своего персонажа. Я так полагаю, это переменные. Как одному java приложению считывать значения переменных другого java приложения?

Comment: никак? Если это делается законно, то есть API соответствующее, если нет - то ломайте игру :)

Comment: Блин, это наверное делать нельзя. А как вообще ломаются игры?

Comment: Скачиваете APK файл, затем разархивируете его. Если разработчик не использовал "шифрование" исходного кода то после декомпиляции можете получить вполне читаемый листинг java кода игры.

Comment: Так я получу дефолтные значения переменных. Мне нужно, чтобы были именно те значения, которые имеет запущенное приложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте  запустить приложение в  эмуляторе (например Bluestack www.bluestacks.com/ru/) запустите кликер любой, выполните необходимые  действия, зациклите  и т.д..
  Если хотите сами написать под андроид, то столкнётесь с тем, что одно приложение не дало разрешение  на  выполнение  действий другому приложению.

Comment: В этом есть проблема. Персонаж не может проходить сквозь движущихся монстров, то есть он может столкнуться с одним и пару шагов пропустится. Соответственно шаблонно тут не катит. Нужно как-то отслеживать, изменились ли координаты персонажа.

Comment: Как вариант: Отслеживать и  анализировать цвет пикселя. делать снимок  экрана и  проводить его полный анализ. Например  бот для  Ив-он лайн так врагов отслеживает , я получал цвет пикселя  используя Robot  на Java или  другие решения, было медленно и криво, но с моей  задачей  справлялось.

Comment: Посмотри в  сторону Sikuli Script http://www.sikuli.org/gaming.html? очень неплохой инструмент, а конкретно глянь там  видео примеры.  Дальше  думаю, сам разберешься)